# How to concatenate a string with the new 1.8 stream API

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Lets say we have a simple method that should concat all names of a Person collection and return the result string.

```
public String concantAndReturnNames(final Collection<Person> persons) {
    String result = "";
    for (Person person : persons) {
        result += person.getName();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Is there a way to write this code with new stream API forEach function in 1 line?

Comment: Consider renaming to "concatenate a string scalar property on a collection of pojos" (with the new....)     Because your question (and the accepted answer) is beyond "a string" IMHO.  Upvote for the question and top answer from me today.

Answer (score 212, accepted):

The official documentation for what you want to do: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html

```
 // Accumulate names into a List
 List<String> list = people.stream().map(Person::getName).collect(Collectors.toList());

 // Convert elements to strings and concatenate them, separated by commas
 String joined = things.stream()
                       .map(Object::toString)
                       .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
```

For your example, you would need to do this:

```
 // Convert elements to strings and concatenate them, separated by commas
 String joined = persons.stream()
                       .map(Person::getName) // This will call person.getName()
                       .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
```

The argument passed to `Collectors.joining` is optional.

Comment: You may want to use String::valueOf instead of Object::toString to have null safety there.